# WPF binding property of viewmodel to dependency property of custom textbox control

Tags: wpf, data-binding, textbox, custom-controls, dependency-properties

I need a **textbox with an additional Property "IsValid" of type boolean**. I then want to **bind that DP to a Property of a ViewModel** of the View thats containing the custom textbox.

Im blocked by `The object of type "System.Windows.Data.Binding" cannot be converted to type "System.Boolean"` when trying to bind the DP.

CustomTextBox.xaml

```xml
<TextBox x:Class="bspProtect.Components.CustomTextBox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:components="clr-namespace:bspProtect.Components"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Name="Root">

    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}"
               TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                            ... Stuff in here
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

CustomTextBox.xaml.cs

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace bspProtect.Components;

public partial class CustomTextBox : TextBox {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty sIsValid =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(IsValid),
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(CustomTextBox),
            new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public bool IsValid {
        get => (bool)GetValue(sIsValid);
        set => SetValue(sIsValid, value);
    }

    public CustomTextBox() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I use it like this in yet another custom control

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="bspProtect.Components.LicenseField"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:components="clr-namespace:bspProtect.Components"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:bspProtect.MVVM.ViewModel.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <controls:LicenseFieldViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <components:CustomTextBox
                     Grid.Column="0"
                     Height="25"
                     MaxLength="8"
                     IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}" <---- This works
                     IsValid="{Binding IsValid}" <---- This complains
                     Text="{Binding SomeText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The ViewModel for that custom control

```cs
using bspProtect.Core;

namespace bspProtect.MVVM.ViewModel.Controls;

internal class LicenseFieldViewModel : ObservableObject {
    public bool IsEnabled => SomeMethod();
    public bool IsValid => SomeMethod();

    public string SomeText {get; set;}

    public LicenseFieldViewModel() {
    }
}
```

However when hovering over the IsValid binding I get this:
`The object of type "System.Windows.Data.Binding" cannot be converted to type "System.Boolean".`

---

*Things I tried*

I noticed that setting a value directly works just fine. ie instead of the {Binding ...} I set it to False/ True directly.

I need this specific behaviour so I want to make this method work. I googled any combination of relevant buzzwords to no avail. I found many similar posts on stackoverflow but couldnt find my specific issue.

I also found some mentions of binding to DPs being impossible (?!).
Someone recommended to Make my CustomTextBox of Type UserControl... but that means its no longer a textbox ?!.

I set the style of the type CustomTextBox elsewhere since that was reported to fix it... but it didnt

Comment: You have ignored the mandatory naming convention for the identifier field of a dependency property. It must be named like the property with the suffix `Property`, i.e. `IsValidProperty` here.

Comment: @Clemens whoa... That fixed it! Thanks a lot. Its a bit scary that variable names matter in WPF. Tiny things like that you need to know when using WPF can sometimes make this a grueling experience. Just getting into WPF.

Comment: It is well documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/custom-dependency-properties

Comment: Yes once you know about it its easy to find. If however youre just starting out and lets be honest not reading walls of text but going to tutorial sites/ youtube you wont discover it so fast. Ofc we should be reading official docs but in real situations thats sometimes not viable. Again thanks for the help its exactly what was wrong! Just in general I question whether its a good idea to have code work only if variables are named in a specific way.